# Mapbox popup displays "unknown" instead of properties

Tags: popup, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

After clicking on a street (which is supposed to display a popup with properties), the popup displays "unknown". What should be done to make the popup show the properties? If anyone knows what to change or what could be the cause of the popups not working, I would be really grateful!

```html
<div class="container" style="background-color:#F6F3F3">
  <div id='map' style='width: 100%; height: 900px;'></div>
  <script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken =

      var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/bisqpski/cjssto8kw77g11gk4rwur575q'
      });


    map.on('load', function() {
      // Add a layer showing the state polygons.
      map.addLayer({
        'id': 'kazimierz-tileset',
        'type': 'fill',
        'source': {
          "type": "Feature",
          "properties": {
            "Street": "Świętego Wawrzyńca",
            "Probability": "13%"
          },
          "geometry": {
            "coordinates": [
              [19.944511, 50.049316],
              [19.94617, 50.049681],
              [19.946307, 50.049719],
              [19.947699, 50.050025],
              [19.948851, 50.050282],
              [19.949689, 50.050456],
              [19.951076, 50.05076],
              [19.951401, 50.050831]
            ],
            "type": "LineString"
          }
        }
      });

      // When a click event occurs on a feature in the states layer, open a popup 
      at the
      // location of the click, with description HTML from its properties.
      map.on('click', 'kazimierz-tileset', function(e) {
        new mapboxgl.Popup()
          .setLngLat(e.lngLat)
          .setHTML(e.features[0].properties.name)
          .addTo(map);
      });

      // Change the cursor to a pointer when the mouse is over the states layer.
      map.on('mouseenter', 'kazimierz-tileset', function() {
        map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';
      });

      // Change it back to a pointer when it leaves.
      map.on('mouseleave', 'kazimierz-tileset', function() {
        map.getCanvas().style.cursor = '';
      });
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Unrelated: I’d delete your personal Mapbox token code from your question if I were you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have `name` as a property for your features. Only street and probability. So you're calling a property that doesn't exist. Use street or define the property name with whatever you want.

```
  "properties": {
    "Street": "Świętego Wawrzyńca",
    "Probability": "13%"
    "Name": "Your Name Here"
  },
```

Or just use the street property.

```
.setHTML(e.features[0].properties.Street)
```

Snippet:

```html
<div class="container" style="background-color:#F6F3F3">
  <div id='map' style='width: 100%; height: 900px;'></div>
  <script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken =

      var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/bisqpski/cjssto8kw77g11gk4rwur575q'
      });


    map.on('load', function() {
      // Add a layer showing the state polygons.
      map.addLayer({
        'id': 'kazimierz-tileset',
        'type': 'fill',
        'source': {
          "type": "Feature",
          "properties": {
            "Street": "Świętego Wawrzyńca",
            "Probability": "13%"
          },
          "geometry": {
            "coordinates": [
              [19.944511, 50.049316],
              [19.94617, 50.049681],
              [19.946307, 50.049719],
              [19.947699, 50.050025],
              [19.948851, 50.050282],
              [19.949689, 50.050456],
              [19.951076, 50.05076],
              [19.951401, 50.050831]
            ],
            "type": "LineString"
          }
        }
      });

      // When a click event occurs on a feature in the states layer, open a popup 
      at the
      // location of the click, with description HTML from its properties.
      map.on('click', 'kazimierz-tileset', function(e) {
        new mapboxgl.Popup()
          .setLngLat(e.lngLat)
          .setHTML(e.features[0].properties.Street)
          .addTo(map);
      });

      // Change the cursor to a pointer when the mouse is over the states layer.
      map.on('mouseenter', 'kazimierz-tileset', function() {
        map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';
      });

      // Change it back to a pointer when it leaves.
      map.on('mouseleave', 'kazimierz-tileset', function() {
        map.getCanvas().style.cursor = '';
      });
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

Lastly, in your example you're adding a layer. But you already have that layer added with the same name in the style you created. You don't need to add it again or you'll get a `Error: Layer with id "kazimierz-tileset" already exists on this map` since it will naturally pull directly from the style. Make sure to rename the layer or remove the `addLayer`.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much! I understand my mistake, but one more question to you: I want my popup to display two properties: the street name so its: e.features[0].properties.Street and probability and my code looks like this right now: .setHTML(e.features[0].properties.Street + ' ' + e.features[0].properties.Probability). But it doesn't work. The popup shows the street name but after that it's once again "undefined" but I defined it. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: Also, I dont quite understand the map.addlayer function. The id of a layer is kazimierz-tileset-2 and it's source is a tileset called "Kazimierz-_tileset" where all the data that needs to be included in the popup is. (the name and the probability). If i remove this layer then I have no data to draw from. Can you explain how should I do it then? I am sorry if I am being troublesome but I really need your help!